# Problems with sorting in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

Playing around in order to learn XSLT, I have the following XML file and XSLT stylesheet. I want to produce a list of the players ranked after the score `3*goals + 2*assists`.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="player_ranking.xsl"?>
<soccer xmlns="http://mysoccer.it"> 
  <players>
    <player>
      <name>Pelé</name>
      <goals>21</goals>
      <assists>9</assists>
    </player>
    <player>
      <name>Beckenbauer</name>
        <goals>7</goals>
        <assists>18</assists>
      </player>
      <player>
        <name>Spiderman</name>
        <goals>27</goals>
        <assists>38</assists>
      </player>
      <player>
        <name>Hagi</name>
        <goals>13</goals>
        <assists>14</assists>
      </player>
      <player>
        <name>Laudrup</name>
        <goals>11</goals>
        <assists>25</assists>
      </player>
      <player>
        <name>Gullit</name>
        <goals>17</goals>
        <assists>15</assists>
      </player>
    </players>
  </soccer>
```

Style sheet

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:soc="http://mysoccer.it"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

   <xsl:template match="soc:soccer">
     <html>
       <head>
    <title>Famous players ranked</title>
       </head>
       <body>
         <h1>Overall ranking</h1>
         <xsl:apply-templates match="soc:players"/>
       </body>
     </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="soc:players">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="soc:player">
       <xsl:sort select="soc:goals * 3 + 2 * soc:assists" order="descending"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="soc:player">
     <xsl:value-of select="soc:name"/> 
     with score
     <xsl:value-of select="soc:goals * 3 + 2 * soc:assists"/>
     <br/>
   </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

In a browser (tried with both Opera and Firefox) it produces

```
 Overall ranking

 Laudrup with score 83
 Pelé with score 81
 Gullit with score 81
 Hagi with score 67
 Beckenbauer with score 57
 Spiderman with score 157
```

Spiderman should appear on top of the list. Can someone point out my error ?

I have used `version="2.0"` in the style sheet as using `version="1.0"` gives me `Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like its doing an alphanumeric sort, so 1 < 5 etc

Try changing the sort line to:

```
<xsl:sort select="soc:goals * 3 + 2 * soc:assists" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
```